# Countably tight well-based spaces are first countable

Tags: general-topology

Some definitions:

- A space is [well-based](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000174) if every point has a neighborhood base well-ordered by reverse inclusion (or equivalently, totally ordered by inclusion).
- A space $X$ is [countably tight](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000081) if for each set $A\subseteq X$ and each point $p\in\overline A$, $p$ belong to the closure of some countable subset of $A$.

Can anyone provide a proof of the following?

> **Proposition:** Every countably tight well-based space is first countable.

---

**Remark:**

A well-based space is automatically [radial](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000172), but it is not true that a countably tight radial space is always first countable.  In fact, countably tight radial spaces are exactly the [Fréchet Urysohn](https://topology.pi-base.org/properties/P000080) spaces.  But there are many such spaces that are not first countable, as shown in [this query](https://topology.pi-base.org/spaces?q=Fr%C3%A9chet+Urysohn%2B%7EFirst+Countable).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a proof:

Let $x \in X$, $\mathfrak {U}$ be a linearly ordered neighborhood base of $x$. 
Define
$A := \{y \in X: \exists \space U  \in \mathfrak {U} 
\space (y \notin U)\}$. 
Then for each $U  \in \mathfrak {U}$ it is  $X \setminus U \subset A$, hence $X \setminus \overline{A} \subset U$.

*Case 1*: $x \notin \overline{A}$.
Then, by the above, $X \setminus \overline{A}$ is the smallest neighrborhood of $x$.

*Case 2*: $x \in \overline{A}$. Then, by countable tightness, there is a countable $B \subset A$, such that
$x \in \overline{B}$. For each $y \in B$ choose
$U_y \in \mathfrak{U}$, such that $y \notin U_y$.
Then $\{U_y: y \in B\}$ is a countable neighborhhood base of $x$.
[Let $U$ be a neighborhood of $x$, w.l.o.g. $U \in \mathfrak{U}$. Then there is a $y$ such that $y \in U \cap B$. Hence, $U_y \subset U$.]

Comment: 12 seconds... If I hadn't stopped to yawn, what might have been. Nicely done :)

Comment: @M W: sorry, for the 12 seconds.  Both were essentially the same proof. Next time it will be on me to delete it ;-)

Comment: Nice.  The fact that $\mathfrak U$ is linearly ordered is used right at the end: Given $y\in U\cap B$, we have either $U_y\subseteq U$ or $U\subseteq U_y$, with the latter not allowed because $y\notin U_y$.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to see it: let $X$ be well-based and $x$ have a minimal witnessing base $\{U_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$ for regular $\kappa>\aleph_0$ where $U_{\alpha+1}\subsetneq U_\alpha$ (that is, $X$ is not first-countable). Then choose $x_\alpha\in U_\alpha\setminus U_{\alpha+1}$, and consider $A=\{x_\alpha:\alpha<\kappa\}$.

We have $x\in\operatorname{cl}(A)$: for every neighborhood $U$ of $A$, choose some $U_\alpha\subseteq U$, then $x_\alpha\in U_\alpha\subseteq U$ is distinct from $x$.

But for each countable $B\subseteq A$, $B\subseteq\{x_\beta:\beta<\alpha\}$ for some $\alpha<\kappa$. Then $U_\alpha$ is a neighborhood of $x$ missing $B$, so $x\not\in\operatorname{cl}(B)$ (that is, $X$ is not countably tight).

Comment: That's the proof I had come up with.